# How frequently cassandra compacting should be done

Tags: performance, cassandra, database, nosql

I have used `nodetool` to do Cassandra Compacting which reduced disk usage from 30Gb to 4Gb.

I know that what the compacting tool does in the background is merge all SST tables to one.

How frequently do I need to run the compact tool, and how will running it manually impact performance?

Comment: You may get a better response on https://serverfault.com (also part of the StackExchange network)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! in the future make sure to ask `questions` in the form of a `question`. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LeveledCompactionStrategy or TimeWindowCompactionStrategy? You generally should not compact the sstables yourself, and if you need to its likely a mismatch in data model to strategy.

The mechanism for when to run depends on the strategy. The most basic; size tiered, will wait until theres a few sstables that are similar sized and merge them. This means if you have time series data or data that gets updated frequently, obsolete data can exist in the larger sstables that will not be merged for a long time.